# Acceptable sources and citations

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations

I would like to accumulate a list of acceptable sources and citations here for the site.
This is because of the following reasons:

- It would be helpful as a reference. We can have this in community bulletin. When writing answers, we might need a source for some important scriptures. It might not be known to everyone. We can share those resources with everyone by posting them here.
- It can serve as a helpful reading material list for new-comers and beginners who are interested in the area.
- We can all agree<sup>1</sup> on some common sources thus creating healthy and to the point discussions.

Please post your answer in the form of a link to the resource. Then a short description of what it covers. Also add related tags<sup>2</sup>.

<sub>1. In comments on posts etc. when wars erupt on the validity of points.


2. Code for adding tags is : `[tag:tag-name]` which renders as [tag-name](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-name)</sub>

Comment: What about the following : 
1. Writings/Speeches /Complete Works of modern masters of Hinduism , such as Vivekananda, Ramana Maharishi, Sathya Sai Baba, Aurobindo, Swami Sivananda, Swami Chinmayananda etc ? 
2. On 1 above, where do we draw the line, what's a good one n what's a bad one, what is about hinduism and what's not ? To give a possibly controversial example, Osho ? 
3. Works of living masters such as Sri Ravishankar, Jaggi Vasudev and Amritanandamayi  etc. 
4. Vast reservoir of regional literature (assume quoting English translationn) such as Dohe, Alwar hymns, Abhangs etc?

Comment: Should we hold strict enforcement until the standard against which something can be enforced is ready ? 
Is there a clarification elsewhere on HInduism Meta, what is a good reference and what is a bad one ? 
In the context of this comment, I am excluding Vedas, Upanishads, Epics and Puranas (and modern commentaries on them)  because they are already known as good sources, I wish to know, apart from those, which ones are quotable and good enough, and which ones are considered anathema, and how can a new user be guided to decide whether he can quote someone or not.

Comment: WhirlMind I am not much active around, so I can't comment. You are welcome to join the Hinduism.SE chatroom and discuss that with fellow regulars. I shall leave a ping for @senshin here in the hope that he looks at it.

Comment: You can find list [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277).

Answer (score 4):

#### [Vedabase.com](http://vedabase.com/en)

The above site has all famous e-books like
Bhagvadgita and Srimadbhagvatam.

Got this link from user @KeshavSrinivasan

#### [YogaUsa.com](http://www.yogausa.com/)

It has all Vedas, Upanishads and many other scripts available in PDF versions.

Answer (score 2):

Probably Bhagavad-gita is the most widely recognized source. I am abbreviating it as BG and adding links to http://bhagavad-gita.org/ (because that site has devanagari, audio, transliteration, word translations, literary translation and 4 different commentaries).

Bhagavad-gita is a chapter from **Mahabarata**, which is also widely popular and a rich cultural reference. It could be naturally abbreviated as MB, e.g.

> [MB Santi 168.5-7] or [MB 12.168.5-7] = Mahabharata Santi parva,
>   chapter 168, verses 5 to 7

These both sources are authored by Srila Vyasadeva, the compiler of Vedas, and discuss the topics of Ishvara (Lord), jIva (living entity), prakriti (matter), kAla (time) and karma (reaction).

People with ISKCON background also abbreviate Bhagavata-purana as SB (Srimad Bhagavatam), Ishopanishad as ISO, and they have some other.

Not so sure if we can recognizably abbreviate these:

- Vedanta sutra
- Manusmriti or Manu Samhita
- Patanjali's Yoga Sutras
- Chanakya Niti Shastra
- Ramayana

**Ramayana** is the other great itihasa (epic) similar in scope and purport to Mahabharata, and also a rich cultural reference.

Related Tags: [bhagavatam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagavatam),[bhagavad-gita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagavad-gita),[mahabharata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahabharata),[bhagavata-purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bhagavata-purana),[ramayana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramayana)