# List out the numerous references provided in answers

Tags: feature-request

A lot of answers on the main site provide wonderful and rare citations and lists of sources.

Is it possible to compile and index these and make them available in one place? The index will have to be a living document, of course.

Comment: As you've tagged with feature-request, are you talking about making an index of resources like [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277) as on meta e.g [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/53/277) one where users can post resources or talking about some feature from system? Can you explain your idea briefly in your question?

Comment: @Pandya I am talking about collating all resources suggested by users in their answers.

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes. This.

I was [ruing about losing a very good resource](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42908608#42908608) which I had found while writing an answer, when Nog Shine directed me to this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). While we know that Stack Exchange would not want to implement a new feature just for our single site, we can instead utilize the [resources which are available to us](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=hinduism.stackexchange.com)! So I went ahead and created a:

## [Granthalayah](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73282/granthalayah)

Named after the sanskrit word for library, we can use that room to add all the resources which we find useful.

#### Using the room

Every resource we find, need to have an associated tag with it, which defines one class of books. Like [puranas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puranas), [historical-books](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-books), [vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vedas), [travelogues](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travelogues). After that we need to have a name for it, the name of the author and of course a link to the resource. A small syntax would be:

```
[tag:resource-type] Book Name - by Book Author | https://link-to-the-resource.website
```

This can easily be extended to verses. For example if we find a new verse, in Purana, we can add a message:

```
[tag:purana] Purana Name - Verse number | Verse in IAST/English
```

#### Advantages

- We can use [tagged searches in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=73282&q=), that is, searching "tagged/vedas", would return us a list of messages which contain that tag.
- We can use the [RSS feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/tagged%2Ftagtype), to get real time updates of the entries in a particular tag.
- We can star important ones, which we like, and then [use the stars page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/73282/granthalayah?tab=stars&filter=mymessages) to easily find them.
- We can use the normal text search to find the resources, or even use the site search in Google to find them.

All this with literally 0 additional effort!