# Are website recommendation questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about website recommendations like [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37674/could-you-give-me-three-or-four-english-websites-of-shaktism-tradition) one on topic?

Comment: You can ask on meta here instead of main site. The main site is considering Hinduism but not a platform to share links (which could break in the future or something else).

Answer (score 2):

For website recommendation, use the meta instead of the main site. Some of my opinions to strengthen my advise:

- Using main site just to throw a link doesn't make sense.
- The website shared can be opinion-based or blocked by region.
- In the future, the link can get expired.
- If you post it on meta, you can discuss as casual as possible without disturbing or breaking any rules of the main site which could be helpful to refer the meta post on the main site as the validity of the source.

Website recommendations can go on this [meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/53/93).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. It's very similar to these which are accepted by the community so I don't see why asking for online resources for one specific sect/tradition like Shaktism should be disallowed:

- [Where can I find/get basic information about Hinduism on the web?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10599/2995)
- [What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15424/2995)